# Recursive function results in StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion

I don't understand why this function results in a stack overflow error. If someone could explain it to me I'd really appreciate it!

```
public static int count7(int n){
    if(n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if (n==7){
        return 1;
    }
    if (n%10 == 7){
        return 1 + count7(n/10);
    }
    else{
        return count7(n/10);
    }
}
```

it works fine with "7777777" and stuff like that, but "999999" give error, aswell as "123" and "47571".

So I added:

```
if(n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
```

and now it seems to work!

Comment: Take the number 123 and see what the execution flow is. Oh also this is a pretty bad example for using recursion (I hope it's just an exercise).

Comment: @ZouZou Why is it a bad use for recursion? And yes it's only an excercise for learning how recursion works and it used.

Comment: Because this is the kind of methods that you could do using a simple loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some situations you have endless recurrsive calls (if n is never equals to 7).

For example:

```
n = 123     //initial call
n = 12    //1st recursive call
n = 1    //2nd recursive call
n = 0    //3rd recursive call
```

The value is never n = 7, therefore you never return anything, and you keep calling count7(n/10)

You should change your code to catch all base cases:

```
public static int count7(int n){
if (n==7){
    return 1;
} else if (n < 7) {
    return 0; // I assumed you wanted to return 0, you can change this to return 1...
}
if (n%10 == 7){
    return 1 + count7(n/10);
}
else{
    return count7(n/10);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
Just to add, does it matter if I do just the if (n <7) shouldn't I have to add if(n > 7) ?

Comment: I would have done if (n <= 7) return 1, but I wasn't sure if you wanted to return 1 just if n == 7. Yes, you can combine to two if you are returning the same value. Update your code above with what you think the answer should be and i'll make comments.

Comment: The first if statement returns if (n == 7), the second returns if (n < 7). Adding if (n > 7) is superfluous because at this point it will always be true (it is not logically possible to reach that code unless n > 7 is true).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have stop condition. You should add there:

```
if (n == 0) return 0;
```

Comment: Just analyze example of 123 in your original code.
1st recursion is returning 0 + count7(12)
2nd recurion is returning 0 + count7(1)
3rd recurion and infinity returning 0 + count (0)

Answer (score 0):

Well, when the two conditions aren't met specifically on the last digit, it simply calls the else block

```
return count7(n/10)
```

with 0 due to dividing a single digit integer with 10, it truncates to 0 and thus does not match the conditions recalling this line until an overflow occurs. You can add a base statement stating

```
if(n==0) return 0;
```

Also, to help the debugging process, I suggest you track your process with print statements to see what is happening with your variables. For example, add

```
System.out.println("n = " + n);
```

before each of the return statements.